# Aggregation in LINQ

Tags: linq

I am new to LINQ. I am stuck with a very silly problem

```
Name    Subjects    Role
----    --------    --------

A       Math        Student
A       English     Student
B       Math        Student 
B       English     Student
C       Math        Student
C       Math        Admin
```

I need result as

```
Name    Subjects        Role
----    --------        --------
A       Math, English   Student
B       Math, English   Student
C       Math            Student
C       Math            Admin
```

I am confused as to how to go about this problem. This is simple in SQL where I can do a groupby clause and get the comma seperated values via a function.

Can someone please help me out?

**Edited**: The three columns are from 3 different sources. I have updated the resultant table. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var grouped = classes.GroupBy(g => new {Name = g.Name, Role = g.Role}).Select(
    s =>
    new
        {
            Name = s.Key,
            Subjects = s.Select(x => x.Subject).Aggregate("", (current, se) => current + (", " + se)),
            Role = s.Select(x => x.Role).First()
        });

var result = grouped.Select(s => new
                                     {
                                         s.Name, 
                                         Subjects = s.Subjects.Substring(2), 
                                         s.Role
                                     }).ToList();
```

This will put your subjects in a comma separated string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If The roles are not identical then?

Comment: You need to do a `GroupBy` on multiple column. I have updated the code, please check now

Comment: Thanks @Abdul. I am using LINQ to Entity and I am getting this error when i execute it on LINQ PAD

NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate[String,String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String, System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Seems like Linqpad doesn't support Aggregate method. You can check this on your project though - it should work

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your code but it should look like this:

```
var grouped = from element in yourList
              group element by element.Name into g
              select new
              {
                  Name = g.Key,
                  Subjects = g.Select(e => e.Subject),
                  // Assuming they are identical when they have the same name
                  Role = g.First().Role
              };
```

Comment: If The roles are not identical then?

Comment: @whihathac Then I've to know what you expect. If you expect a sequence of roles then exchange `g.First().Role` with `g.Select(e => e.Role)`. Besides, if you want it as a comma separated string, then use `string.Join` locally, or as mentioned in the other answer `Aggregate`.

Comment: @whihathac I didn't look at your result table long enough. Use multiple grouping as Abdul mentions.